# socket io, sharing socket across multiple client webpages

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Suppose I have a webpage that initiates communication with the server onload, as below:

**index.html:**

```
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    socket.on('message', function(message) {
        alert('The server has a message for you: ' + message);
    })
</script>
```

Now client uses index.html to fill in a form and send it to the sever for processing. Upon submission of the form, he is redirected to a new page, say, **processing.html**, which I would like to continue communication with the server (for example to show the log of progress)

But I suppose that if within 'processing.html' I have the same 'script' block as above, a new socket will be created. So my question is if there is anyway to carry the socket object created on the **index.html** page on to **processing.html** to continue communication with the server?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try linking socket with express session [like this](https://howtonode.org/socket-io-auth). or  [this](https://botleg.com/stories/using-your-sessions-with-socketio/) 
Then You may try to store information in session.